# How come sometimes images wont show when using the full path?

Tags: php, html

I have this php code:

```
$images=array();
    $root = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'SV';
    for ($i=1; $i<=$total_pics; $i++){
        $images[]=$root.'/ad_images/'.$category.'/thumbs/'.$id_stripped.'_'.$i.'.jpg';
    }
```

And here I display the image:

```
<?php for ($n=1; $n<count($images); $n++): ?><img src="<?php echo $images[$n];?>"><?php endfor; ?>
```

But this wont show the image, only a square-box that shows when image is not found.

When I click on properties on the box, the full path is actually correct, and the image file IS THERE, but it act as if it is not there.

**HOWEVER, when I use the relative path, it works just fine! Why?**

Thanks

Comment: If you copy the full path from the properties box, and paste into a browser, does it work?

Comment: it says protocol (c) is not associated with any program! So no, it doesn't work!

Comment: Seems the path starts with c: ?
this is not valid for the browser, it should rather be
file://c:

[see Matts answer]

Comment: Ah and btw: the image path should not be the full path on the hard disc, but rather the path from your htdocs dir, which is probably
    /SV/ad_images/ etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the HTML output? If you're using an absolute path, I would imagine the output looks something like this (on a linux server):

`<img src= "/var/www/path/to/image.jpg"/>`

Which wouldn't work unless you used the `file://` prefix:

`<img src="file:///var/www/path/to/image.jpg"/>`

And even then, it would only work on a local browser.

Comment: +1 
The $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] is probably not on the server inside of the document root itself. /var/www/html/var/www/html probably doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

Typically `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` shows the file system path and not the web server path.

When you use a relative path, it's from the web root of the site.